# Can you assign a string from 2 strings?

Tags: c

I'm still new here, but I came across questioning why I was under the belief that the below could not be done.

I'm trying to assign foobar to the value of "Hello there!\n". Either it can't be done, or I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

EDIT: I need to clear up that I'm looking for why the below does not work, not 1 of many solutions that can take it's place.

EDIT: I took the answer of "You can not concatenate strings variable in c in that way." Presumably because it was too difficult to write the parser to allow the below way. I'm too new to know any different, and too new to be so concerned. If anyone ever finds a formal reason with citation, please post it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

char *foo = "Hello";
char *bar = " there!\n";
const char *foobar = (*foo) *bar;

printf("%s", foobar);

return 0;

}
```

This doesn't seem like it should be a problem.

Comment: You're looking for `snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s%s", foo, bar)`

Comment: @cnicutar: Yes, that is what I have been doing, but I never thought about trying the above way first. After I thought about it, I thought why not? What I'm trying to do is logical, doesn't seem harmful.

Comment: why dont you simply concatenate foo and bar and then assign it to foobar.

Comment: Is `foo` and `baa` know at compile-time?

Comment: @Jack: Why wouldn't foo and bar be known at this point? If I was assigning integer values to foo and bar, the I could use + to operate on them, thus adding foo and bar together.

Comment: Because if it know at compiler-time you make them constant and then const `char *foobaa = FOO BAA;`will work fine as `char *s = "a" "b";`you can't use `+` operator in the C to concat two strings.  The `+` in C perform only sum of two integers(and pointers,which are number technically). The reason is because it's as the C language was projected. To be simple. Simple enough to be used instead of assembly language without loss performance and too many time writing the parser, consuming the programmer. The memory of mainframes(and later computer) in such epoch doesn't help too. Was too few.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can not concatenate strings variable in c in that way.

You need a memory space in which you will copy both strings in that memory.

The memory space could be a static buffer like `char foobar[100]`if you already know that the size of your strings could not be bigger than the defined size. Or the memory could be dynamiuc buffer if you do not know the limit size of your string as indicating in the following example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

   char *foo = "Hello";
   char *bar = " there!\n";
   char *foobar = malloc(strlen(foo) + strlen(bar) + 1);
   strcpy(foobar,foo);
   strcat(foobar,bar);
   printf("%s", foobar);

   return 0;

}
```

If you allocate the memory with `malloc()` then do not forget to free the `foobar` memory whene it become useless in your program with

```
free(foobar);
```

Comment: And surely we could use a buffer of, say, 100 bytes rather than call malloc in the first place.

Comment: and maybe a `if(foobaa) {` before `strcpy()`s and `printf()`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Why? can't be the strings greater than `100`-size? Well,I believe that `foo` and `baa` and its values are examples only. If such strings are constants,just use `char* foobaa = FOO BAA;`

Comment: Of course, if there is a reason to believe strings are long enough to overflow 100 bytes, you need to do something to cope with that. But my point is rather that people VERY often suggest "use malloc", when in fact a simple local array would be perfectly good and will avoid the problem of having to free the alloocated string - allocating memory to hold a 7 byte array is quite wasteful. In both Windows and Linux, allocations can easily take up 16-32 bytes of "overhead" on top of the allocated size - so at least double the size of the actual string in this case.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: What you are suggesting about not using malloc() is the very reason why I started to question. In fact, I got ride of a malloc call, then replaced it with [99]. I then further question even doing that and wanted to use automatic storage. Which led me to trying what I posted. However, every way I tried above (the above was just the last thing I tired), it wouldn't work. For now, I'm assuming the answer is maybe I'm not supposed to know why it was designed not to work the way I posted. Truthfully, I'm just going to go on doing it the ways I've been shown and forget about it.

Comment: @Mohamed KALLEL: I'm giving you the answer because you put it as it appears to be... "You can not concatenate strings variable in c in that way."

Answer (score 3):

In C, strings can't be concatenated with the way you do. One possible way which mimics what you are trying do is to make use of preprocessor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FOO "foo"
#define BAR "bar"

int main()
{
char *foo = FOO;
char *bar = BAR;
const char *foobar = FOO BAR;

printf("%s", foobar);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right, but when dmr, or whoever set out in how string assignments work, what led them to not allow what I posted?

Comment: I know some other languages do that but not C. For e.g. in `bash` you can do that with: `foobar=$foo$bar` but not in C. `foo` and `bar` are pointers to string literals and are not replaced with their values in C.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the "edited" question:

It doesn't work because the C language as such has no knowledge of how to concatenate strings. You are supposed to use `strcat` or some other function. Further, the compiler wouldn't know where to put the string in memory, snce it can't use the storage for "foo" and "bar" to store the resulting string.

Of course, in C, the meaning of `*foo` in your code is the letter `'H'`, and `*bar` turns into `' '`. So `(*foo) *bar` becomes `('H') ' '` which has absolutely no useful meaning in C.

Comment: Surely you mean `*foo` turns to 'H' and `*bar` turns to '(space)'.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at one of the answers, which had "foo" and "bar" as strings... Fixed, and clarified a little bit.

Comment: Right, I understand. But that didn't even work. It was just a question of logic of the language itself. I'm giving up looking for the logic. It really is not worth the bother being it can work other ways.

Comment: Yes, it really is "you can't do that in C" (for arbitrary strings, without strong limitations and using macros, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Your code probably compiles with no problem but there are some possible mistakes in there.

First two char* (or string) declarations are legit. 
The third one not that much. 
You are casting (*bar) as *foo, wich is not a data type but a variable, and you set foobar to that casted value of foo, instead of doing string concatenation.

C doesn't do string concatenation with operators. Instead, you need to use specific libraries to concatenate strings or make your own functions. For strings you have [string.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/string.h.html)

For this particular case, you have [strcat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strcat.html): It takes two strings and returns a new string with the concatenation of those two strings.

So, for your example:

```
char *foo = "Hello";
char *bar = " there!\n";
const char *foobar = malloc((strlen(foo)+strlen(bar))*sizeof(char));
foobar = strcat(foo,bar);
```

Something like this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: a)sizeof(char) is redundant as it always evaluates to 1.
b) you can't use strcat() like that. foo is not a valid destination.